# How show a variable data into html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have 2 html files and their name is `index1.php`& `index11.php`.  `index11.php` is showing a json data into a html table. I want that my `index1.php` to give same result as `index11` is giving now. Please edit or make some change so that it give desired result. Right now `index1.php` is just showing a json data. And I don't know next steps for showing in a table format.

index1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="jsencode.js"></script>
    <script>
        function display() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", "crc.php");
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var aa = this.responseText;
                document.write(aa);
                /**
                 * 
                 * here i dont know how do next steps
                 * 
                 **/
            };
            request.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result">
</div>

<h1 id="head">Welcome to Our Website</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
        <button onclick="display()">Click here to Get Courses</button>
        <div class="head">
            <h1 style="margin-left:35%;margin-right:auto;:block;margin-top:2%;margin-bottom:0%"></h1>
        </div>

        <table id="category" width="100%">
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index11.php

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</header>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function display() {
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON('crc.php', function (data) {
                $.each(data.liveClasses, function (i, f) {
                    var link = "index3.php?id=" + f.Id;
                    var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Name" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Id + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Info" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.messageName + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Link" + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='" + link + "'>" + "Get INFO" + "</a></td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Teacher" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Is Live Now" + "</td>" + "<td>" + (f.liveClassStatus === '2' ? 'Yes' : 'No') + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "-" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "-" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                    $(tblRows).appendTo("#category tbody");
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<h1 id="head">Welcome to Our Website</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
        <button onclick="display()">Click here to Get Courses</button>
        <div class="head">
            <h1 style="margin-left:35%;margin-right:auto;:block;margin-top:2%;margin-bottom:0%"></h1>
        </div>
        <table id="category" width="100%">
            <thead> </thead>
            <tbody> </tbody>
        </table>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add your json data ?

Comment: index11.php is working so copy some code from index11.php and paste in index1.php

Comment: @virender nehra Please answer my query

Comment: Both files have dangling `</tr>`

Answer (score 0):

In your `index11.php`, you have:

```
    $.each(data.liveClasses , function(i, f) {
        var link ="index3.php?id="+ f.Id;
         var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Name" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Id + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Info" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.messageName + "</td>" + "</tr>" +"<tr>" + "<td>" + "Link" + "</td>" +"<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+"Get INFO"+"</a></td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Teacher" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Is Live Now" + "</td>" + "<td>" + (f.liveClassStatus ==='2' ? 'Yes' :'No') + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "-" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "-" + "</td>" + "</tr>" ;

         $(tblRows).appendTo("#category tbody");
     });
   });
```

In this section, the data you get from other source is saved in variable `data`. After that, it will iterate through the data, and append the html code containing each row of data.

But in your `index1.php`, you have just shown the raw data without inserting it in proper html code:

```
    var aa = this.responseText;
    document.write(aa); // this is when you show the raw data
```

To resolve this, you can try these steps:

1. Parse the result to JSON: `var data = JSON.parse(aa);`
2. Copy the code from `index11.php`:

```
    $.each(data.liveClasses , function(i, f) { // liveClasses is a property of data
        var link ="index3.php?id="+ f.Id;
         var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Name" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Id + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Info" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.messageName + "</td>" + "</tr>" +"<tr>" + "<td>" + "Link" + "</td>" +"<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+"Get INFO"+"</a></td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Teacher" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Is Live Now" + "</td>" + "<td>" + (f.liveClassStatus ==='2' ? 'Yes' :'No') + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "-" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "-" + "</td>" + "</tr>" ;

         $(tblRows).appendTo("#category tbody");
     });
   });
```

Note: I don't know your JSON response text's detail, so if you have problem when using those codes, make sure that you have used the right properties in that JSON.

Comment: sir please make  index1.php such that it give same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just looping the data:

```
let jsonData= [{id: 1, name: "jhon"}, {id: 2, name: "jane"}]

jsonData.forEach((d) => {
  $("#app").append(`<p>${d.name}</p>`)
})
```